# Solve $\int^{305}_{0} 4\pi \left(\frac{0.039948}{((2\pi)8.3145)500}\right)^{3/2}x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My attempt at problem 1, taken from [here.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.01%3A_Gas_Phase_Kinetics/3.1.02%3A_Maxwell-Boltzmann_Distributions#)
\begin{align*}
&\int^{305}_{0} 4\pi \left(\frac{0.039948}{((2\pi)8.3145)500}\right)^{3/2}x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)dx\\
&=4\pi \left(\frac{0.039948}{((2\pi)8.3145)500}\right)^{3/2}\int^{305}_{0} x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)dx\\
&=2.37669\times 10^{-8}\int^{305}_0x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)dx\\
&=2.37669\times 10^{-8}\int^{305}_0x^2\exp\left(0.039948x^2\frac{1}{(2)(8.3145)(500)}\right)dx&&\left(\frac{a \cdot b}{c}=a\cdot\frac{b}{c}\right)\\
&=2.37669\times 10^{-8}\int^{305}_0x^2\exp\left(0.039948x^2\frac{1}{8314.5}\right)dx\\
&=2.37669\times 10^{-8}\int^{305}_0\exp\left(4.80462\times10^{-6}x^2\right)xxdx&&(a^{b+c}=a^b+a^c)\\
\end{align*}
Using integration by parts, where $u=x$ and $v'=\exp(4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2)$, we have
\begin{align*}
u'&=\frac{dx}{dx}=1\\
&\\
v'&=\int\exp(4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2)xdx\\
&=\int\frac{e^u}{(4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2)}du\\
\end{align*}
Using $u$-substitution, we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dx}\left[4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2\right]\\
&=4.80462\times 10^{-6}\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2\right]\\
&=9.60924\times 10^{-6}x\\
\end{align*}
Hence, we have $du=9.60924\times 10^{-6}x dx$ and $dx=\frac{1}{9.60924\times 10^{-6}} du$, which becomes
\begin{align*}
&=\int\frac{e^u}{9.60924\times 10^{-6}}du\\
&\frac{1}{9.60924\times 10^{-6}}\int e^u du\\
&=104067\int e^u du\\
&=104067 e^u\\
&=104067 \exp(4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2)+C\\
\end{align*}
Putting it all back together, we have
$$=2.37669\times 10^{-8}\int^{305}_0104067 \exp\left(4.80462\times 10^{-6}x^2)\right)xxdx$$
Now, using again $u$-substitution, we have $du=0.00219194$ and $dx=\frac{1}{0.00219194}du$, which becomes
\begin{align*}
&=104067\int \exp\left({4.80462\times 10^{-6}}^{1/2}x\right)^2du\\
&=104067\int e^{u^2} 0.00219194 x^2du&&(1)\\
\end{align*}

I got stuck here and $(1)$ didn't seem correct.

I checked my notes, and would $\int e^{u^2} du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erfi}(u)$ be useful here? Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: How did the argument of the exponential function become suddenly positive?

Comment: Apologies, this was an error on my end. I'll edit it accordingly.